# How to test iPhone app on iOS 3.1.3?

Tags: iphone, testing, ios-simulator, ios

I have an iPhone app which I need to test in an older version of iOS. In the iPhone Simulator, under the Hardware->Version menu, there are the options 3.2 and 4.0. Is it possible to test the app on an older version of the iOS? If so, how do I make it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you kept your old build of xcode (that has the 3.1.3 simulator) or you have a device running 3.1.3 you are more than likely out of luck.